# Xamarin UITest iOS Tab Badge Query in Repl Not Found

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

In the Repl I ran a query for "1" which is the current badge number on a tab.

This returned the below query, which you can see has the class _UIBadgeView.

However when I run a query for _UIBadgeView I get nothing.

I tried both `app.Query("_UIBadgeView");` and `app.Query(c => c.Class("_UIBadgeView"));`

Any ideas how I can access the badge view?

```
{
Id => null,
Description => "<_UIBadgeView: 0x7e5cd380; frame = (49.5 2; 18 18); text = '1'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7e5cceb0>>", Rect => {Width => 18, Height => 18, X => 145.5, Y => 621, CenterX => 154.5, CenterY => 630
},
Label => "1",
Text => "1",
Class => "_UIBadgeView",
Enabled => false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious and maybe a bug, but underscore is not treated as an uppercase character. Use `ClassFull` instead of `Class` for an iOS class name that begins with underscore.

> For iOS (first char lowercase): An element that has the class (or
>   super class) name of the given value prepended with "UI". Example:
>   button becomes UIButton. For iOS (first char uppercase): An element
>   that has the class (or super class) name of the given value.

[AppQuery.Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.Class/p/System.String/)

> For iOS: An element that has the class (or super class) name of the given value.

[AppQuery.ClassFull](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery.ClassFull/p/System.String/)